# oEmbed in Symfony 3 implementation

Tags: symfony, oembed

I want to allow user creating [oEmbed](http://oembed.com/) content to my website.
There is a lot of information how to implement it but none about creating a enpoint.

1. Quick question: is there some ready php code samples for `creating` (returning) oEmbed response for third party websites?
2. If no, how to create it? Ex youtube link looks like this:

   http://www.youtube.com/oembed?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DiwGFalTRHDA

   and the response is :

   ```
   {
       "html": "<iframe width=\"459\" height=\"344\" src=\"https://www.youtube.com/embed/iwGFalTRHDA?feature=oembed\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe>",
       "thumbnail_height": 360,
       "thumbnail_width": 480,
       "provider_name": "YouTube",
       "author_url": "https://www.youtube.com/user/KamoKatt",
       "thumbnail_url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/iwGFalTRHDA/hqdefault.jpg",
       "author_name": "KamoKatt",
       "provider_url": "https://www.youtube.com/",
       "type": "video",
       "version": "1.0",
       "width": 459,
       "title": "Trololo",
       "height": 344
   }
   ```

   My question is: how they know which video it is? They are using regexp to parse `videoID`?
3. What is 'best practice' for this kind of request? Should it be created as Controller, Service, Provider or how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I have created it like this:

1. I have created a service:

```
namespace AppBundle\Service;

use AppBundle\Entity\PlaceMarker;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
use Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\Exception\Exception;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception as Ex;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Matcher\UrlMatcher;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\RequestContext;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Route;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\RouteCollection;


class EmbedService
{

    CONST THUMBNAIL_WIDTH = 400;
    CONST THUMBNAIL_HEIGHT = 300;
    CONST HTML_WIDTH = 459;
    CONST HTML_HEIGHT = 344;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    protected $baseUrl;

    /**
     * @var array
     */
    private $params = [];

    /**
     * @var EntityManager
     */
    private $entityManager;

    /** @var \Twig_Environment */
    private $twig;

    public function __construct($baseUrl, EntityManager $entityManager, \Twig_Environment $twig)
    {
        $this->baseUrl = strtolower($baseUrl);
        $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
        $this->twig = $twig;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param Request $request
     * @param null $format
     * @throws \Exception
     */
    public function handleRequest(Request $request, $format = null)
    {
        $this->params = [];

//        $baseUrl = $request->getSchemeAndHttpHost();

        /** handle url parameter */
        $this->params['url'] = $request->query->get('url');
        if (!$this->params['url']) {
            throw new Ex\BadRequestHttpException('A URL parameter must be provided');
        }

        /** check if url matches site url */
        $this->params['path'] = substr($request->query->get('url'), strlen($this->baseUrl));
        if (substr(strtolower($request->query->get('url')), 0, strlen($this->baseUrl)) !== strtolower($this->baseUrl)) {
            throw new Ex\BadRequestHttpException('This is not a valid URL parameter');
        }

        /** handle format parameters */
        $this->params['format'] = $format;
        if (null === $format) {
            $this->params['format'] = $request->query->get('format', 'json');
        }

        if (!in_array($this->params['format'], ['json', 'xml'])) {
            throw new \Exception('Disallowed format parameter \'' . $this->params['format'] . '\'');
        }

        $maxWidth = $request->query->get('maxwidth', null);
        if (is_numeric($maxWidth) || is_null($maxWidth)) {
            $this->params['maxWidth'] = $maxWidth;
        }

        $maxHeight = $request->query->get('maxheight', null);
        if (is_numeric($maxHeight) || is_null($maxHeight)) {
            $this->params['maxHeight'] = $maxHeight;
        }

        $this->params['attr'] = $this->matchRoute($this->params['path']);
    }

    public function matchRoute($path)
    {

        $route1 = new Route('/place-marker/{id}/show', ['controller' => 'PlaceMarkerController']);
        $routes = new RouteCollection();
        $routes->add('place-marker', $route1);

        $context = new RequestContext('/');

        $matcher = new UrlMatcher($routes, $context);

        try {
            return $matcher->match($path);
        } catch (\Exception $ex) {
            throw new Ex\NotFoundHttpException('No implemented!');
        }
    }

    /**
     * @return array
     */
    public function create()
    {
        if (!$this->params) {
            throw new Exception('Unable to create oEmbed. Did you use handleRequest() first?');
        }

        $oEmbed = [
            'version' => '1.0',
            'provider_url' => $this->baseUrl,
            'provider_name' => 'Pixdor.com'
        ];

        switch ($this->params['attr']['_route']) {
            case 'place-marker':

                /**
                 * @var PlaceMarker $pMarker
                 */
                $pMarker = $this->entityManager->getRepository(PlaceMarker::class)->find($this->params['attr']['id']);

                $oEmbed['title'] = $pMarker->getName();
                $oEmbed['url'] = $pMarker->getUrl();
                $oEmbed['description'] = $pMarker->getDescription();
                $oEmbed['caption'] = $pMarker->getCaption();

                $oEmbed['html'] = $this->twig->render(':place_marker:embed.html.twig');
                $oEmbed['width'] = self::HTML_WIDTH;
                $oEmbed['height'] = self::HTML_HEIGHT;

                $oEmbed['rich'] = 'photo';
                break;
        }

        $oEmbed['thumbnail_width'] = isset($this->params['maxWidth']) ? $this->params['maxWidth'] : self::THUMBNAIL_WIDTH;
        $oEmbed['thumbnail_height'] = isset($this->params['thumbnail_height']) ? $this->params['thumbnail_height'] : self::THUMBNAIL_HEIGHT;

        $oEmbed['thumbnail_url'] = sprintf('http://placehold.it/%dx%d', $oEmbed['thumbnail_width'], $oEmbed['thumbnail_height']);

        return $oEmbed;
    }

    /**
     * Returns format type (json|xml)
     * @return string
     */
    public function getFormat()
    {
        if (!$this->params) {
            throw new Exception('Unknown format type. Did you use handleRequest() first?');
        }

        return $this->params['format'];
    }

}
```

services.yml

```
app.embed:
    class: AppBundle\Service\EmbedService
    arguments: ["%base_url%", "@doctrine.orm.entity_manager", "@twig"]
```

parameters.yml

```
base_url: "http://project.local"
```

next in the controller:

```
/**
 * @Route("/oembed.{_format}",
 *     name="embed",
 *     defaults={"_format": null}
 * )
 * @param Request $request
 * @param $_format
 * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
 * @throws \Exception
 */
public function generateAction(Request $request, $_format)
{

    $oEmbed = $this->get('app.embed');
    $oEmbed->handleRequest($request, $_format);

    $view = View::create()
        ->setFormat($oEmbed->getFormat())
        ->setStatusCode(200)
        ->setData($oEmbed->create());

    return $this->handleView($view);
}
```

you call it like this:
http://project.local/oembed?url=http://project.local/place-marker/4/show